# Is this a good coding practise- Passing Connection around?

Tags: java, jdbc

Here is my story. I have `myCon=getUnusedConnection();` method that get a connection from Connection pool. I also have a `releaseConnection(myCon);` method to release Connection to the pool after finishing using it.

Ok, When coding, I need to select data from Database many times & cos I wanna reuse my code so I wanna have many methods for 1 single Action. Ex,

```
public static List<String[]> getData(){
    Connection myCon=null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt=null;
    try{
        myCon=getUnusedConnection();
        String sql="select ........";
        preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
        String str="";
        if(results.next()){
             str=results.getString(1);
        }
        if(!str.equals("")){
             List<String[]> list=getData2(myCon, preparedStmt, str);
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
    }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
    }
    finally{
        releaseConnection (myCon);
        closeStatement (preparedStmt);
    }
    return null;
}

public static List<String[]> getData2(Connection myCon, PreparedStatement preparedStmt, String str){

     try{
         List<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]>();
         String sql="c.......";
         preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
         ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
         while(results.next()){
             list.add(results.getString(1));
         }
         return list;
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                              ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
    }catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
    }
    finally {

        closeStatement(preparedStmt);
        releaseConnection(myCon); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do i need to include `try - catch - finally` in getData2?
Since I am passing `myCon & prepareStatement` around so I am not sure is this the right way to code.

Is it a standard way for what I am coding? or do u do better coding?

Comment: If you have working code and are worried about good design practice, you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I'd made your method `getData2` not public and if you can't change it, i'd make another method, not being public.. and only manage `try -catch finally` in one method.

Comment: I would suggest you close your `Connection`, `ResultSet` and `Statement` Objects in whichever method opens them (and in the order they are opened). I also suggest you use my code from [this](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/clean-up-after-yourself.html) blog post.

Comment: @nachokk, can u clarify? so i don't need try-catch-finally in getData2?

Comment: @Elliott, it gonna cost more energy. Suppose if the pool run out of connection, then it have to open another connection & that costly

Comment: How does the order you close them in "cost more energy"? Or in which method(s) you call close...

Comment: @MinhHai i just make it an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> Do i need to include `try` - `catch` - `finally` in `getData2`?

The answer depends on other places from which you call `getData2`:

- If `getData` is the only place, then the answer is "no", a `try`/`finally` would be sufficient.
- If there are other places all of which expect a `SQLException` and process it in the same way, the answer is also "no", for the same reason (no `catch` is required).
- If there are other places, some of which do not expect `SQLException`, then you need to keep the `try` - `catch` - `finally`

However, there is a problem with the way that you coded your call of `getData2`: since `getData2` has a `finally` that releases the connection, your `getData` releases the connection twice. You need to either add a `useExistingConnection(conn)` and modify your `releaseConnection` in a way to count references to the same connection, or pass a flag that indicates whether or not the connection should be closed.

Generally, I would prefer to structure the code to open and close the connection in the same method, pass the connection around to other methods, and use `try`/`finally` only to close the `PreparedStatements` opened inside subordinate methods, such as `getData2`.

Comment: since i use ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery(); in getData2, so i need try catch.

Comment: @MinhHai Yes, you would need a `try`/`finally` to deal with the result set and the prepared statement only. You shouldn't be closing the connection that has been passed into `getData2`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd made your method `getData2()` private and not catching (if it handle the exception same as parent) and closing resources in finally if you do in top level. If you can't change it, make another method private for example `getData3()` without `try-catch-finally`.

However i'd made another change, if all of your methods follow the same template.

The callable interface for calling.

```
public interface Queryable<T>{
    T execute();
}
```

Then the util class.

```
public final class SQLUtil {

    private SQLUtil() { }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return getUnusedConnection();
    }

    public <T> static  T query(Queryable queryable) {
        T toReturn = null;
        try {

            toReturn = queryable.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            while (ex != null) {
                System.err.println ("SQL Exception:  " +
                ex.getMessage ());
                ex = ex.getNextException ();
            }
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
        } finally {
            releaseConnection (myCon);
            closeStatement (preparedStmt);
        }    
    }

    //add code for getUnusedConnection, releaseConnection, closeStatement    
}
```

And yor client code will look like this:

```
public List<String[]> getData(){
    return SQLUtil.query(new Queryable<List<String[]>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String[]> execute() {
            Connection myCon=getUnusedConnection();
            String sql="select ........";
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet results=preparedStmt.executeQuery();
            String str="";
            if(results.next()) {
                str=results.getString(1);
            }
            List<String[]> list = null;
            if(!str.equals("")) {
                list=getData2(myCon, preparedStmt, str);
            }
            return list;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for ur code, but I using the same structure for 100 or more methods, so if i use ur method then i need to change all. I think I can like close all & reconnecting the COnnection,since connection in the pool so it not a big deal

Comment: If you are following the same structure, using `Template Method` is a good choice ;), keep in mind!

Comment: @MinhHai if you are following the same structure, using Template Method is a good choice ;), keep in mind! But the good thing of this if that you have to change anything. you only remove repetitive code :)